# How to get position of each item in page with scrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page like this

[image]

I Open an Overlay widget based on the position of each item.
i get this position with these codes

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  final RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  setState(() {});
});
```

the problem is that when I scroll to top parts of this messaging list offset.dy of that I get from this code is just keeps going down and this offset is not based on the page that is being shown but based on the list.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive solution presented by [boeledi](https://gist.github.com/boeledi) is what you are looking for.

```
 Rect _getPosition(BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final Offset topLeft = box.size.topLeft(box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero));
    final Offset bottomRight =
        box.size.bottomRight(box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero));
    return Rect.fromLTRB(
        topLeft.dx, topLeft.dy, bottomRight.dx, bottomRight.dy);
  }
```

and translating it by the offset of the `Overlay`

```
    final Rect widgetPosition = _getPosition(context).translate(
      -overlayPosition.left,
      -overlayPosition.top,
    );
```

Inside of the widget tree use `CustomSingleChildLayout`:

```
CustomSingleChildLayout(
    delegate: _OverlayableContainerLayout(widgetPosition),
    child: child,
),
```

And change position delegate.

```
class _OverlayableContainerLayout extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  _OverlayableContainerLayout(this.position);

  final Rect position;

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return BoxConstraints.loose(Size(position.width, position.height));
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    return Offset(position.left, position.top);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_OverlayableContainerLayout oldDelegate) {
    return position != oldDelegate.position;
  }
}
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/boeledi/bc852dea6ed7f65f99a5e121168eb40d)